# Using addbasemap command in ArcObjects.NET?

Tags: arcobjects

Here I executed the save edit command programmatically

```
      pUid.Value = "{59D2AFD2-9EA2-11D1-9165-0080C718DF97}"   'save edits
      pCmdItem = pApp.Document.CommandBars.Find(pUid)
      pCmdItem.Execute()
```

How do I execute the addbasemap command programmatically in ArcObjects.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#858a508c-b771-467c-81e6-c6aa72d88f9c.htm) is the page to get the latest class ID.
It is located in the help files under `ArcObject help for .NET developers / Developing with ArcGIS / Learning ArcObjects / General ArcObjects references / Names and IDs / ArcMap commands`

The `Add Basemap` command ID is     `{76B26001-63CF-4CAC-A7E0-91CEE8686FAC}`